# How can I display data using sectionList in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to display data using section List in react native. I am extracting data using `reduce()` but I am not able to understand why I am getting undefined behaviour saying please provide html or uri as prop for `react native render html`.

I want to display sectionList items as HTML content and title of SectionList is the title from `specificationsData`.

```
const specificationsData = specifications.reduce( (acc, curValue) => {

            if (curValue.title !== undefined && curValue.description !== undefined){

                let newObj = {};

                newObj['data'] = curValue.description;

                newObj['title'] = curValue.title;

                console.log(curValue.title)

                acc.push(newObj);

                return acc;
            }

        }, []);

        console.log(specificationsData)
```

Result of above log:

[image]

Now I pass above data into `SectionList`:

```
import HTMLView from 'react-native-render-html';

<SectionList
                    renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <HTMLView key={index} value={item}/>}
                    renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
                        <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'red'}}>{title}</Text>
                    )}
                    sections={specificationsData}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
                />
```

How can I pass display data and title of `sectionList` by passing `specificationsData` ?

See screenshot of above code:

[image]

Comment: Post the result from [these changes](https://pastebin.com/bfnJzBUb), as I think your issue most likely has something to do with `({section: {title}})`.

Comment: @FrankerZ See screenshot -> https://imgur.com/a/eRxb63f this code -> `<Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'red'}}>{title}</Text>` is perfect I think there is some issue with `HTMLView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`SectionList` documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist#section), data needs to be an array within your `specificationsData`. Update the following line:

```
newObj['data'] = [curValue.description];
```